# T wave analyis and extraction using discrete wavelets

Tags: wavelet

I'm doing a project in T-wave extraction from ECG signal. Initially I completed the preprocessing steps like noise removal and baseline drift cancellation. Then I need to extract T wave using discrete wavelet transform. I tried different wavelets for different level in wavelet, but I'm not able to extract the T wave.

Can you help me with MATLAB coding?

Comment: MATLAB programming questions are more appropriate for [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). Even then, your question does not contain enough information for anyone to be able to help you. I suggest you move the question to Stack Overflow, provide references to the literature you are using, and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not an easy task to automate. An algorithm that works great on clean ECGs can fail miserably on noisy ones. That said, I would suggest you look at the approach used to identify the ST segments in the [Long Term ST Database](http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/ltstdb/lt00/node2.html). It is one of, if not the, largest ST segment database publicly available. They describe the approach they used, which includes automatic segmentation followed by expert review.

Also, take a look at the [PhysioToolkit](http://physionet.org/physiotools/) from [PhysioNet](http://physionet.org/). I'm pretty sure the have some automatic ECG annotation tools. I looked, but couldn't find them. Still, I think they are there somewhere.